# system runAs method to verify if the user can access a record

Tags: apex, unit-test, apex-sharing, system.runas

I have below test class which verifies whether a use have access to the record or not. The Campaign__C object's sharing setting is Private. However with below test class when I run the SOQL the 2nd User is able to access the record even though the Campaign record was created by first user.

```
@isTest
public class shareTest {

    @isTest
    public static void shareRecordTest(){
        List<User> campTeamUsers = TestData.createTestUsers('ProfileName', 2, 0);
        insert campTeamUsers; // Create 2 different users
        Test.startTest();
        List<Campaign__c> campList = new List<Campaign__c>();
        System.runAs(campTeamUsers[0]){ // insert a Campaign__c as 1 User
            campList = TestDataUtility.createTestCampaigns('Camp Share Test',1); // Creates only 1 Campaign
            insert campList;
        }
        System.runAs(campTeamUsers[1]){ // Check if other User have access
            List<Campaign__c> result = [select Name,id from Campaign__c];
            system.debug('result is ' + result);  // 2nd User able to see Campaign__c record
        } 

        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there Sharing Rules on Campaign__c? Does the test user profile have View All permission, or View All Data? Do the test users have Roles?

Comment: Ah right , i guess the profile had view all looks like. I am gonna try with a different profile

Comment: N.B. If you are using criteria-based sharing rules, [these can't be tested in apex](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_sharing_rule_types.htm&type=5)